# How to compute visible bounds for Asus Xtion Pro Live sensor

Tags: math, computer-vision, kinect, trigonometry, asus-xtion

I've got a basic setup using an [Asus Xtion Pro Live sensor](http://www.asus.com/Multimedia/Xtion_PRO_LIVE/#specifications) with the sensor suspended at 3m above ground looking straight down. I'm trying to work out the visible bounds in meters.

Here's a diagram to illustrate this:
[image: Asus sensor setup above ground]

I know the FOV angles:

```
Field of View
58° H, 45° V, 70° D (Horizontal, Vertical, Diagonal)
```

I though about using a bit of trig to work it out.
If I take the HFOV, half it and imagine the right angled triangle formed,
I could could use the tangent (opposite / adjacent), knowing the angle to work out the opposite side:

```
opposite = adjacent * tan(29)
opposite = 3m * tan(29)
opposite ~= 2.66m
```

Just to test, I've also put together a very basic program using [Processing](http://processing.org) and [SimpleOpenNI](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni) to measure: mark two points, get the 3D coordinates and compute distance.

```
import SimpleOpenNI.*;

SimpleOpenNI ni;
PVector m1,m2,p1,p2;
PVector[] realWorldMap;

void setup(){
  size(640,480);stroke(0,192,0);
  ni = new SimpleOpenNI(this);
  if(!ni.enableDepth()) exit();
  ni.alternativeViewPointDepthToImage();
}
void draw(){
  ni.update();
  realWorldMap = ni.depthMapRealWorld();
  image(ni.depthImage(),0,0);
  if(m1 != null && m2 != null) line(m1.x,m1.y,m2.x,m2.y);
  if(p1 != null && p2 != null) text("distance :"+(int  )(p1.dist(p2)*.1)+" cm",5,15);
}
void mouseReleased(){
  if(!keyPressed){
    m1 = new PVector(mouseX,mouseY);
    p1 = realWorldMap[mouseY*640 + mouseX];
  }else{
    m2 = new PVector(mouseX,mouseY);
    p2 = realWorldMap[mouseY*640 + mouseX];
  }
}
void keyPressed(){
  if(key == ' ') m1 = m2 = p1 = p2 = null;
}
```

I've got ~2.6 as the widest measurements, but I'm slightly confused because I thought that the opposite side is only half of the frustrum's base width, so was expecting ~5.3m. Are my assumptions wrong ? If so, what am I doing wrong/what's the correct way to calculate this ?

I've also used the Kinect tag, because the same principle applies for the kinect sensor as well

Answer (score 1):

It might be more convenient to calculate this in Excel or OpenOffice Calc.

As a rule of thumb, the horizontal field of view (as a linear width) of the Kinect is about 1.1 times the distance from the sensor. More inexactly, the width of the image at a given distance D from the sensor is the same as the distance D, especially if you've merged the color and depth images and have black depth pixels around the edges.

```
D = distance from sensor
theta = angular field of view of Kinect = 57 degrees

tangent (angle) = opposite/adjacent

tan (theta/2) = (ImageWidth/2) / D
D * tan (theta/2) = ImageWidth/2
2 * D * tan (theta/2) = ImageWidth

ImageWidth(D) = 2D * tan(28.5 degrees)
```

For example,

```
ImageWidth(1.0m) = 2 (1.0) * tan(28.5 degrees) = 2 * (1.0) * 0.543 = 1.08m
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert degrees to radians first:

```
tan(29 degrees)=tan(0.5061 rad)=0.5543.
```

Thus, `opposite=0.5543*3m=1.663m`
and the horizontal visible bound is `2*opposite=3.33m`

Therefore, the rule of thumb mentioned above is a good estimate (`3m*1.1=3.3m`).